# newrelic - Browser monitoring

Tags: newrelic

For my application i am trying to get browser monitoring data. Using following  api getBrowserTimingHeader, getBrowserTimingFooter.  But i could find any header and footer  added after xsl transformation.

Configuration :

browser_monitoring:

```
auto_instrument: true
enabled: true
enable_custom_tracing: true
```

Can someone help me why the above API is not adding header and footers.  Does API have any pre-requisite to return header/footer information.

Answer (score 2):

In order for New Relic to produce the header and footer scripts for real user monitoring, the API must be called from within a web transaction. If you call the API outside of a web transaction (in a background transaction, for example) the API call will not return the scripts you're expecting: the return value will be null or an empty string. You can see https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work for more info on how real user monitoring works.